# SetState inside UseEffect causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

```
export const Upload = ({ initialfileList = [] }) => {
  console.log("called...")
  const [files,setFiles] = useState(initialfileList)
  useEffect(() => {
    setFiles(initialfileList)
  }, [initialfileList])
  return(
    .....
   )
}
```

I will not be sending initialfileList in intial render.
so I'm trying to update the state (files) when intialfileList value Changes.
But I'm not able to get why code is going into infinite loop.. Can someone help...

EDIT:
what I'm trying to achieve is there are two uploads in the form (say upload A and upload B) and checkbox as well. when the user uploads an image (say imgc) in Upload A and hits the checkbox, I wanted img c to be autouploaded in Upload B as well..

Comment: How did you know that it's in infinite loop?

Comment: By logging in the console..

Comment: The only potential problem I can guess is that `initialfileList` is updated in the parent constantly. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I see. How about this?

```
export const Upload = ({ initialfileList = [] }) => {
   const [files, setFiles] = useState(initialfileList);
   useEffect(() => {
      function isDifferentFiles(originFiles, newFiles) {
         return originFiles.length !== newFiles.length; // or whatever logic here.
      }
      if (isDifferentFiles(files, initialfileList)) {
         setFiles(initialfileList);
      }
   }, [initialfileList]);
   return <div>{files.length}</div>;
};
```

Btw, you might need to consider move the state to parent.

Comment: But the intialfileList will not be sent in the initial render.. the file will be sent only when checkbox is checked.

Comment: can you identify the reason why it is going into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to lift your state up - rather than storing fileLists locally, store a single fileList in the parent component, pass that down to both Upload A and Upload B, and also pass a `setFileList` function (which updates the state in the parent component).

i.e.:

```js
// parent component
const Parent = () => {
    const [fileList, setFileList] =  useState([])
    return (
        <Upload fileList={fileList} setFileList={setFileList} />
        <Upload fileList={fileList} setFileList={setFileList} />
    )
}
```

```js
const Upload = ({fileList, setFileList}) => {
    return (
        <UploadComponent files={fileList} onUpload={setFileList} />
    )
}
```

This way, either upload component being updated will update both.